# Django - get_redirect_url() causes Page not found (404)

Tags: django

I'm trying to implement favorite feature so that user can choose favorite stores. I'm currently referencing the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkPRtQf6oQ8&t=542s and stuck with the beginning.

When I try to move to the url `https://www.fake-domain.com/my-domain/like`, it throws the error message saying `No Store matches the given query.` So, I guess `self.kwargs.get("domainKey")` this snippet seems to throw the error, but I don't know why.
I'm not sure if I'm showing my codes enough, so please let me know I need to show more.

**models.py**

```
class Store(models.Model):
    ...
    domainKey = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
    ...
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<store_domainKey>.*)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<store_domainKey>.*)/like/$', views.StoreLikeRedirect.as_view(), name='like'),
```

**views.py**

```
class StoreLikeRedirect(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        store_domainKey = self.kwargs.get("domainKey")
        print(store_domainKey)
        obj = get_object_or_404(Store, pk='store_domainKey')
        return obj.get_absolute_url()
```

**--------------------------------EDIT------------------------------**

Revised the codes based on the feedback, but still not working.
When I typed the url, the terminal says the following:

```
None <-- this is shown by print(store_domainKey) in views.py
Not Found: /down-east/like/
```

Since the print function in views.py prints `None`, I think there's something wrong on the line `store_domainKey = self.kwargs.get("domainKey")`. The part `self.kwargs.get()` seems not working. In the example video at the top of the post, the guy used `SlugField()`, but I used `CharField()` for my `domainKey`. Can it be an issue to use `self.kwargs.get()`?

**views.py**

```
class StoreLikeRedirect(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        store_domainKey = self.kwargs.get("domainKey")
        print(store_domainKey)
        obj = get_object_or_404(Store, domainKey=store_domainKey)
        return obj.get_absolute_url()
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<store_domainKey>.*)/like/$', views.StoreLikeRedirect.as_view(), name='like'),
url(r'^(?P<store_domainKey>.*)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Store(models.Model):
    ...
    domainKey = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('boutique:detail', kwargs={"domainKey":self.domainKey})
```

**----------------------------2nd Update-----------------------------**

So, now `self.kwargs.get("domainKey")` returns the domain key very well!
but having

```
NoReverseMatch at /down-east/like/
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'domainKey': 'down-east'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<store_domainKey>.*)/$']
```

Comment: Most likely, your URL is getting captured by the first pattern which matches everything. You should swap the order of that patterns, or preferably make them more specific.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated my codes based on your feedback, but still now working. I think I narrowed down the suspicious problem, can you check that again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you are using a string instead of the variable you created. And you probably need to filter on the field `domainKey` instead of `pk`.

Try changing

```
obj = get_object_or_404(Store, pk='store_domainKey')
```

to

```
obj = get_object_or_404(Store, domainKey=store_domainKey)
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I forgot putting it back after having tried something before. Anyways, fixed the typos but still has not working. I updated the post.

Comment: @Jay after looking at your update, have you tried using `store_domainKey` instead of `domainKey` in `self.kwargs.get("domainKey")` ? Looking at your urls it says `?P<store_domainKey>` so you should try that.

Comment: Thanks! Now, `self.kwargs.get("store_domainKey")` returns the domain key value! However, it looks having a problem for redirecting. I put the error message on the post. If you don't mind, can you also check that?

Comment: @Jay that error says it received the keyword argument `domainKey` but expected `store_domainKey`. You have to modify the models `get_absolute_url()` method as well.